# Adding watermark to the video when its uploaded to the S3 bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, video-watermarking

I need to add watermark to videos uploaded to S3 bucket automatically. What would be the best and most scalable approach? I don't have much experience and its a bit challenging for me.

I've tried using fluent-ffmpeg on the node backend, but its time and resource consuming and not scaling at all, so i want to move processing part on the AWS

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Amazon Elastic Transcoder** or **AWS Elemental MediaConvert** to do this automatically, rather than processing the videos with your own code.

See:

- [Watermarks - Amazon Elastic Transcoder](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/watermarks.html) or
- [Using image inserter (graphic overlay) in AWS Elemental MediaConvert - MediaConvert](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/latest/ug/graphic-overlay.html)

Comment: it's a great suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

AWS Lambda functions is what you're after.  You can [automatically tigger the lambda when an object is added to S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html) or for more robust operation, have [S3 write events to an SQS Queue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ways-to-add-notification-config-to-bucket.html) and have [a lambda process queue messages](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html).

Comment: There may be some limitations wrt video file size, assuming that the entire S3 object has to be downloaded to Lambda in order to run ffmpeg.